# How to find totals from Dictionary by keys property in Swift 5

Tags: swift

How can I find the totals by `brand` from a dictionary of `[Product: Double]`?

`Product` has a property `brand`.

```
let items = [Item]

let productTotals = items.reduce([Product:Double()) {(result, item in 

  var result = result
  let product = item.product

  // Calculate the total product width
  result[product] = product.width * item.count

  return result
}

// Now find the totals for each brand by summing the values for Product.brand
let groupTotals = productTotals ???
```

Example

```
items = [{ix = 1, product = A, count = 1}, {ix = 2, product = B, count = 2}, {ix = 3, product = C, count = 2}]

products = [{name = 'A', width = 1.0, brand = 'BA'}, {name = 'B', width = 2.0, brand = 'BA'}, {name = 'C', width = 1.0, brand = 'BB'}]

productWidths = [(A: 1), (B: 4), (C: 2)]
brandWidths = [(BA: 5), (BB: 2)]
```

Comment: Can you give us a full, compilable example with some sample data?

Comment: Use `reduce(into:)` to form a histogram.

Comment: @matt more details or example?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica - if I could do that I wouldn't be asking

Comment: `items = [{ix = 1, product = A, count = 1}, ` isn't valid Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding @matt's suggestion - I didn't realise you can seed a default value and I forgot that the same product might occur more than once.

```
let productSpace = items.reduce(into: [Product:Double]()) { result, item in

   if let product = item.product {
                result[product, default: 0.0] += product.width * item.count
                }
            }

let brandSpace = productsSpace.reduce(into: [Brand:Double]()) { result, productSpace in
            if let brand = productSpace.key.brand {
                result[brand, default: 0.0] += productSpace.value
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` to group your items up, and then `mapValue` to transform the groups in the desired ways.

I see two ways of doing this. The first is more like your way, except I've use standard library functions to achieve what you did with product totals

```
let items = [Item]()

let products = items.map { $0.product }

// This is your "productTotals"
let productTotalWidths = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    products.lazy.map { (product: Product) -> (key: Product, value: Double) in
        let totalWidth = product.width * product.count
        return (key: product, value: totalWidth)
    }
)

let productTotalWidthsBrand = Dictionary(grouping: productTotalWidths, by: { $0.key.brand })
    .mapValues { (pairs: [(key: Product, value: Double)]) -> Double in

        return pairs
            .lazy             // don't allocate intermediate array
            .map { $0.value } // pull out the totalWidths calculates earlier
            .reduce(0, +)     // sum them
    }
```

However, as you can see, the second step is made a bit harder, because you need to regroup the dictionary (from being grouped by `Product`, to being grouped by `Brand`), which then involves flattening the inner groups (which are grouped by `Product`).

This could could be simplified by instead first grouping by brand, then doing the rest:

```
let items = [Item]()

let products = items.map { $0.product }

let productsByBrand = Dictionary(grouping: products, by: { $0.brand })


let productTotalWidthsByBrand = productsByBrand.mapValues { products in
        return products
            .lazy                        // don't allocate an intermediate array 
            .map { $0.width * $0.count } // calc total width per product
            .reduce(0, +)                // sum them
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite there because the $0.count is actually a property on the Item. So products by brand grouping loses the Item and so you can't do the calculation.  I think maybe @matts suggestion might be easier - see my answer.

Comment: `$0.count is actually a property on the Item` And that's precisely why I asked for a compiable example. I'm wasn't asking for a comparable *solution*, but a test fixture to get us started, with all the correct data types `Item`, `Product`, `Brand`, whatever, and some sample data, and some expected result. Without that, we're just gonna end up playing comment-ping-pong, guessing at your unclear criteria.